# Windows XP immediately logs out after logging in

Tags: windows-xp, login, logoff

Trying to fix my friends computer and having some issues. (Windows XP)

The story is, he plugged in his Blackberry, didn't have the software, so installed it. It wanted to restart so he did, and it tried to log in, flashed the desktop, then immediately logged out (no taskbar, etc, just desktop wallpaper and back out).

Went to shutdown the computer and it wanted to install updates. These were the updates of doom and caused a BSOD. I was able to fix the BSOD by following the standard steps of booting to the Recovery Console, and uninstalling the offending update. The computer was able to boot, but now am still faced with the auto log out.

I searched and found the "boot to recovery console and copy userinit.exe to wsaupdate.exe" solution but that didn't work, and that seems to be the only stuff I can find relating to this problem. Booting to safe mode results in a BSOD.

What are my next options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a [**system restore from the recovery console**](http://forums.cclonline.com/showthread.php?1183-System-Restore-from-Recovery-Console) back to when it was all working okay.

Failing that, try a [**repair installation**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxprepair1.htm).

Comment: Despite being a good suggestion, I've never had a system restore work, EVER, and neither did that method :)

Ended up formatting from scratch, since I really hate repair installs.